# SQLite LEFT JOIN ELSE

Tags: sqlite, left-join

I have 2 tables: Items and their prices. Some items don't have prices. How do I LEFT join prices to items, and if no match is found for an item, give it price value 0?
P.S.

```
items (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, imgurl text, defindex int, name text)
prices (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, defindex int, quality int, effect int, currency text, price real
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An outer join will return NULL for all fields in a table row that does not actually exist because there is no match.

To convert NULLs into any other value, use the [ifnull function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull):

```
SELECT items.name,
       prices.currency,         -- might be NULL
       ifnull(prices.price, 0)  -- might be 0
FROM items
LEFT JOIN prices USING (id)
```